# HashMap Iterator/ForEach loop

Tags: foreach, iterator, hashmap, return, program-entry-point

Just a quick question I got regarding HashMaps. Basically I have two strings. Both have a certain number of similar words in each string. The following HashMap method allows me to count how many times a certain word comes up in each sentence. My problem is returning this method in a main method. The HashMap method is the following:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getWordCounts(){
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.getWordArray().length; i++){
        String key = getWordArray()[i];
        Integer count = map.get(key);

        if(count == null){ 
            count = 1;
        }else{
            count++; 
        }   

        map.put(key, count);

    }
        return map;
}
```

This is what I've gotten so far for my return method.

```
        HashMap<String, Integer> hashMapAdd = map.getWordCounts();
    for(HashMap.Entry <String, Integer> entry : plato.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ "," + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Am I going the right way with the return method? I feel like i'm going off into a wrong direction.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Is something particularly going wrong?

Comment: Yeah, Im unsure on how to print out the results from the HashMap. This hashmap is in another class, and I want to print out the results in a separate main class.

Comment: What is the `map` variable? Which type is it? Which class contains the `getWordCounts` method?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the logic of the function(i have not analyzed it), about what you asked...
Yes, this method is perfectly alright to construct and return HashMap like this in Java, when i started working with java after working on C++ for 2 years, i also got confused sometimes, but than i understood that it is perfectly alright to return local objects in java, because garbage collector of JVM handles the issues which might occur in C++ using this technique.
Now, you got hashmap, to iterate through and print hashmap just use a loop like this:

```
for(String key:hashMapAdd.keySet())
     System.out.println(key+ "," + hashMapAdd.get(key));
```

At least for me this is less confusing and easy.
For details of HashMap visit:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

P.S: I have assumed that your code is compiling(you didn't complained any compilation errors), because the line  map.getWordCounts(); seems suspicious, i have assumed that this method is in some class named map. But in that case you would not be able to make HashMap with Name map, you need to look why are you using map in this line of code.